# Angular 2 way for creating wrapper component

Tags: angular, reactjs, angular2-template

In my angular 2 redux app for root component I use next template:

```
<div class="app">
  <custom-header></custom-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <custom-footer></custom-footer>
</div>
```

So, I have the same header and footer on every route. And I would like to create something like this for every app component: some container which will add some common styles for every page (for example: panel with custom title and page custom html).
In React for this I could create next components:

```
const CustomWrapper = ({ title, sidebar, children }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>{title}</h2>
    { sidebar &&
      <div className="sidebar">{sidebar}</div>
    }
    <div style={{some condtitional styles}}>{children}</div>
  </div>
);
```

and then

```
const SidebarPage = () => (
  <CustomWrapper
    title="Title from state or"
    sidebar={<div>JSX template for sidebar</div>}
  >
    <div>JSX template for page content</div>
  </CustomWrapper >
)
```

and use SidebarPage for some route. 
So, CustomWrapper can be used for every page for same styling and has custom parts according to props and some conditions.

What is angular 2 way for this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can create Header and Footer components that take in @Inputs from the main component, or you can update them with services depending on the route you take.

```
@Component{}
export class Header implements OnInit {

    constructor(private myService: RouteChangedService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.myService.routeUpdated().subscribe(data => { this.updateView(data) } )
    }
}
```

In this manner you can have a constant header and footer like you had above:

```
<header></header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer></footer>
```

And call routeUpdated on component instantiation to inform them of the new route and to update their views and logic accordingly.  You may also be able to leverage the router to call these services based on route name, but I haven't done that myself.

Comment: I meant a little other functionality: this I already have and need wrapper only for content in  `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` for setting common conditional styles.

Comment: Hmm, in that case you could wrap the router-outlet in a div (or maybe apply the class directly?), then use ngClass with state variables from the parent component to drive the styles applied to the wrapper.

Comment: And how about conditional html? Can I use something like `props.children` from react in angular 2 (`<custom-html>some othre html which rendered in a specified place</custom-html>`)?

Comment: A couple ways: *ngIf to conditionally display elements, or bind to <div [innerHtml]="your string">, where your string can change conditionally.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I guess it's not best practise for angular 2. In react it looks more natural.

Comment: no problem -- was having a bit of trouble visualizing it, but I think there are ways to do what you're wanting.